# How to use $.ajax() function to get URL from a search bar and display the HTML response in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

HTML:

```
    <div id="browse-container">
      <input type="search" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search URL..."></input>

      <button id="search-button">Search</button>
    </div>
```

Above I have a search input where the user should be able to type in any URL.

Script:

```
    $('#search-button').click(function(){
      var HTMLresp = $('#search-bar').val();

      $.ajax({
          url: HTMLresp,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          type: 'GET'
      });
            $('body').append('<div id="result-window"></div>');        
            $("#result-window").html(HTMLresp); 
    });
```

Now when the user clicks on the button the specified url is to be placed in a variable 'HTMLresp' and then that URL should be placed inside of the ajax function. After ajax function is done the HTML response of the specified URL should be displayed in a the result window div on the page.

But right now the page just displays the string version of the URL.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyersjared/pmfqj4p2/2/)

Comment: It shows the URL because you aren't doing anything with the response at all (not that you can, since the Same Origin Policy will prevent you access the data from arbitrary URLs).

Comment: This is a duplicate [of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) however, your bigger problem will be the Same Origin Policy on third party websites.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
$('#search-button').click(function(){
  var HTMLresp = $('#search-bar').val();
  $('body').append('<div id="result-window"></div>'); 
  $.ajax({
      url: HTMLresp,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
          $("#result-window").html(data);
      }
  });
});
```

This way, when your request finishes, and is succesfull, the response data will be placed inside your div. You should put an error handler as well, this is just a rough example.

Keep in mind the following line:

```
$('body').append('<div id="result-window"></div>');
```

This will be executed each time the user clicks the `#search-button` element, You should place the div `#result-window` directly in your dom, or append it on document load, otherwise you will end up having a lot of divs with id `#result-window`

I also recommend you to read about CORS and JSONP a little, because what you want to do as a lot of limitations, you cannot ask for resources from different domains (You can, with jsonp as you do, but it has its limitations as well).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP